# Unable to access nmap command via system() function in R

Tags: linux, r, windows, nmap

I am trying to create a reconnaissance scanning tool in R. It requires me to run `nmap` system tool installed in Windows 10 machine. I can run the command `nmap`from command prompt but I am unable to invoke the same through `system()` function in R.

The function I wrote and the corresponding output follow

```
nmapper <- function(opt="-F", ip)
{
  cmd = paste("nmap", opt, ip, sep=" ")
  getter = system(cmd, intern = T)
}
```

Output is as follows :

```
> nmapper(ip="www.google.com")
```

> Error in system(cmd, intern = T) : 'nmap' not found

Now, I don't know if the same happens in linux and I should be careful. 
As usual R community wants me to specify the following details, so here we go

- RStudio : 0.99.486
- Machine : Intel Corei5 (64 bit) with radeon graphics
- OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)
- R: 3.2.2

Comment: Your R version and Rstudio version are weird.

Comment: `devtools::session_info()` is your friend. `system2` is generally preferred on Windows over `system`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant test it, but you probably want to call `cmd.exe` with the `/C` flag to terminate.

```
system("cmd.exe /c nmap -F", intern=TRUE)
```

You could also use `shell` which has the "/c" flag by default.

```
shell("nmap -F", "cmd.exe")
```